# file_put_contents write the last row only

Tags: php

I'm trying to write some data from database table into a gfg.txt file by file_put_contents(). By checkboxs I select more events and then I need to save some informations from them into gfg.txt, but only the last one event is saved into that file.
So then I tried to print to video the gfg.txt and I get all the events correctly, but if I open the same file from the server there is only one record, or the last one event from the selected.

How can I print all the records I need into the gfg.txt file? Thank you

So in the file I have:

> TITOLO: ryjss, DESCRIZIONE: brsrt, DATA: 2019-07-01

But on screen I have:

> TITOLO: enr g, DESCRIZIONE: efbve, DATA: 2019-07-04
>
> TITOLO: ggfef, DESCRIZIONE: veegert, DATA: 2019-07-06
>
> TITOLO: yriey, DESCRIZIONE: tyjdh, DATA: 2019-03-01
>
> TITOLO: ryjss, DESCRIZIONE: brsrt, DATA: 2019-07-01

The value is got from esporta.html.php:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="esportazione[]" value="<?="TITOLO: ".$evento['titolo_evento'].", DESCRIZIONE: ".$evento['desc_evento'].", DATA: ".$evento['data_evento'];?>"/>Seleziona<br/><br/>
<input type="submit" name="btn_export" value="Esporta"/>
```

In the following export_txt.php I try to save the informations in the txt file:

```
<?php
  if(isset($_POST["btn_export"]))  {

    if (!empty($_POST["esportazione"])) { 
?>

  <p><a href="gfg.txt">Download</a></p>

<?php
  foreach ($_POST["esportazione"] as $esportazione) {
        $file = 'gfg.txt';
        $current= $esportazione;
        file_put_contents($file, $current);

        echo "<pre>";
        echo htmlspecialchars(file_get_contents($file));
        echo "</pre>";

        }
    }
   }
?>
```

Comment: Read the [documentation](https://www.php.net/file_put_contents). You'll note there's a flag you can pass that will append to the file rather than replace.

Comment: I know, but i need to replace the file every time. thank you

Comment: Then what is your question / problem? Each loop iteration overwrites the previous iterations content.

Comment: you need change to  `file_put_contents($file, $current, FILE_APPEND)`

Comment: My problem is my code only save into gfg.txt file the last event from those I selected. I'd like to save all. If I append I have a loop

Comment: By the by, if you're expecting multiple users to hit this script, possibly at the same time, you may be in for some race conditions / unexpected output.

Comment: @datone And that output is wrong, because?  So assuming what you _actually_ mean is you want to add all this data to a clean file when the script runs, then you can clean the files before the foreach, and use append within. But Nigel's Answer also works.

Comment: There is only one user. The use in internal to the office, a publisher needs to send those data to graphics

Comment: @Jonny Sorry, maybe I can't understand. Now I can save just one record from my selection. If I add FILE_APPEND, I will get all selected record, but in the following way: record1 | record1 record 2 | rerecord1 record 2 record 3 and so on. But I need to get: record1 | record 2 | record 3 etc. Can you post some code?

Answer (score 0):

Currently your `foreach` loop acts on 1 item at a time, so it will fetch the data, overwrite the file and then display the contents.  But this contents is only ever the last line written as your display is inside the loop.

As you just seem to want all of the values from that array into the file, you could reduce it to use `implode()` (using a new line as the glue) and write all of the contents in one go, so instead of the `foreach` loop, just have...

```
  $file = 'gfg.txt';
  file_put_contents($file, implode(PHP_EOL, $_POST["esportazione"]));
```

and then check it with...

```
  echo "<pre>";
  echo htmlspecialchars(file_get_contents($file));
  echo "</pre>";
```

Comment: Thank you so much @Nigel, it works finally! You all are the best!